# Wine and Ubuntu 13.04 - 64 Bit

Tags: 13.04, apt, wine, 64-bit

I have been trying to install Wine on my 13.04 64 bit computer, and everytime it leads to synaptic asking for the uninstall of the entire system.

I have been following some questions which suggest the addition of the Wine repository (also recomended on the WineHQ) website, followed by `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install wine1.5`.

### The system cries, with the following messages:

```
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Certains paquets ne peuvent être installés. Ceci peut signifier
que vous avez demandé l'impossible, ou bien, si vous utilisez
la distribution unstable, que certains paquets n'ont pas encore
été créés ou ne sont pas sortis d'Incoming.
L'information suivante devrait vous aider à résoudre la situation : 

Les paquets suivants contiennent des dépendances non satisfaites :
wine : Dépend: wine1.6 mais ne sera pas installé ou
             wine1.7 mais ne sera pas installé
E: Impossible de corriger les problèmes, des paquets défectueux sont en mode    « garder en l'état ».
```

**English translation:**

```
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... done
Some packages could not be installed. This can mean
you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using
the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet
created or are not moved out of Incoming.
The following information should help you to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine: Depends: wine1.6 but will not be installed or
              wine1.7 but will not install
E: Unable to correct problems, faulty packets mode "keep state".
```

I have tried all `sudo apt-get autoclean` and `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get update`. However, the problem seems to continue. Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

My French is quite rusty, but I think what I am reading is telling me that you are trying to install the latest version of Wine, but you do not have the earlier versions installed that it depends on.

However you can add the Wine PPA and download it this way:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Then update the package lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and now install:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

That should work for you.

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, I have already added the Wine PPA as mentioned in the WineHQ Website. I have asked the question because this is not working, the new repository.